# sforce.console.isInConsole() self changing value inside embedded VF Page

Tags: javascript, service-cloud-console

I have problem with Service Console, fragments of code below is from VF Page which is embedded in standard case page:
`<apex:commandLink value="History" onclick="openHistory('{!product.id}')" />`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openHistory(objId) {
        if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
            sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(function(res){
        sforce.console.openSubtab(res.id, '/'+ objId, true, '',null);
                });
            } else {
                window.open('/'+objId);
                return;
        }
     }
</script>
```

The problem is `sforce.console.isInConsole()` flag in service console, on first click it shows `true` and everything works well, but second and next cliks are faulty because flag is set to `false`. 
Does anybody know what could happen here?

Comment: i faced same issue while working on service cloud. My root cause was. Are you reloading page with url(www.ap1.salesforce/apex/vfpagename).

Comment: My root cause was ... - can You extend it  (; 
What You mean by reloading? I enclosed code where I am opening a new tabs.

Comment: How did You workariund It?

Comment: Im talking about main page. add alert on main page and check whether it will be on console or outside of console page. alert(sforce.console.isInConsole());

Comment: My page is nested in OOTB (standard Case) page

Comment: alert works in nested page too.

Comment: I know what You mean, I added console.log('sforce.console.isInConsole - ', sforce.console.isInConsole()); And it pints in console true for first time, and false for every nect clicks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've found a known limitation of embedded VF pages with forms. When you "submit" the form by clicking the commandLink it reloads the VF page inside of the case layout. This causes it to lose some of the context it needs to identify itself as part of the console, which is why it returns false for future clicks.

One workaround is to add a 'return false;' statement to your onclick as such

```
<apex:commandLink value="History" onclick="openHistory('{!product.id}');return false;" />
```

It will prevent the form submission and therefore the refresh of the page and the isInConsole will continue to work.

Comment: Sounds very good! I wtill Try maybe tonight and give comment.